# Wordpress - Open an Advanced Custom Field image in modal box using Featherlight.js

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, advanced-custom-fields, featherlight.js

I have tried to code my wordpress theme as simple as possible but I don't really understand why I can't display an image from Advanced Custom Field into a modal box using Featherlight.js (http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/)

Here is my online page http://www.skuar.com

This is my single.php code, which simply display the image custom field

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and this is the wp loop content

```
<div id="post">
    <a href ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <div class="img" href="<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>" data-featherlight="image">
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    </a>

</div>
```

I just would like to open the image in a lightbox...
Is that make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In invalid double quotes in your code. Try this code:

```
    <div id="post">
        <a href ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="img" href="<?php  $image = get_field('image');
                if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                <?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>" data-featherlight="image">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Awesome. It solved my issue. But very weird actually, it works great on my local server (using MAMP), but not online. I just uploaded exactly the same files. Do you know why?